# Canvas.getContext is not defined

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I've looked around, and the only replications of my issue that I've seen have been using jQuery, which I'm not doing.  My problem is, I have, in my html, a canvas element:

```
<canavs id="background" width="620" height="620"></canavs>
```

That's all.  I have JavaScript, but it's all classes and I'm not calling any of the functions or creating any instances or anything at all. It may as well not be there at all. I'm going INTO THE CONSOLE and typing:

```
let a = document.getElementById("background");
```

Then, when I type `a` in the console, it confirms that it is indeed a canvas element.  However, when I type `a.getContext`, it returns `undefined`. Calling the function - `a.getContext("2d")` - throws an error about the function being undefined.  I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what's going on.  I've never had this problem, and I've done plenty of work with canvases.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in spelling `canvas`

Comment: Honestly, I'm laughing so hard for not spotting that myself. Well done! +1 :P

Comment: I'm CACKLING oh my god thank you

Comment: Hehe... happens with everyone! :)